# Is it possible to "vectorize" successive matrix multiplications?

Tags: python, optimization

I am in the process of "vectorizing" a pet project of mine. The function 'propagateXi' propagates (solves) a time-varying, linear system of equations and answers to ~20% of the cost of the project.

The sizes vary a lot between instances of the problem. A "typical" set would be: N = 501, n = 4, s = 3.

Here is a simplification of the code:

```
import numpy

class Propagator():

  def __init__(self,mode):
    # lots of code here
    pass

  def propagateXi(self,Xi,terms):
    """ This function propagates the linear system, called many times with different initial conditions.
        The initial conditions were previously set.
        The "arc" represents a kind of "realization"; 
        the arcs are essentially independent from one another.

        Sizes: "vector dimensions": 2*n, "time dimension": N, "arcs dimension": s 
         - Xi (N, 2*n, s) stores the (vector) state in each time and each "arc".
         - self.MainPropMat (N, 2*n, 2*n, s) stores the 2n x 2n matrices 
         - terms (N, 2*n, s) stores the "forcing terms" of the equation.

        The equation would be something like:
          \xi_{k+1, arc} = MainPropMat_{k, arc} * \xi_{k, arc} + terms_{k, arc}  \forall k, arc
    """
    
    for k in range(self.N - 1):
      Xi[k+1,:,:] = numpy.einsum('ijs,js->is', self.MainPropMat[k, :, :, :], Xi[k, :, :]) +\
                      terms[k, :, :]
    return Xi
```

I have tried to re-interpret the problem as the multiplication of a huge 2nN x 2nN matrix by a long 2nN column containing the initial conditions and the forcing terms. In these conditions, the code was something like this:

```
import numpy

class Propagator():

  def __init__(self,mode):
    # lots of code here
    self.prepareBigMat()

  def prepareBigMat(self)
    """
    Prepare the "big matrix" for Xi propagation. Called only once.

    This function assembles the "big matrix" (s x 2*n*N x 2*n*N !) for propagating
    the Xi differential equation in a single step.
    :return: None
    """

    n2 = 2 * self.n
    BigMat = numpy.empty((self.s,self.N * n2,self.N * n2))
    I = numpy.eye(n2*self.N)
    for arc in range(self.s):
      BigMat[arc,:,:] = I
    for k in range(1,self.N):
      kn2 = k * n2
      BigMat[:, kn2:(kn2+n2) , 0:kn2] = numpy.einsum('ijs,sjk->sik',
                                            self.MainPropMat[k-1,:,:,:],
                                            BigMat[:,(kn2-n2):k*n2, 0:kn2])
    self.BigMat = BigMat

  def propagateXi(self,Xi,terms):
    
    n2 = n * 2
    # Assemble the big column
    BigCol = numpy.empty((n2 * N, s))
    # Initial conditions
    BigCol[:n2, :] = Xi[0, :, :] 
    # Forcing terms
    BigCol[n2:, :] = terms.reshape((n2 * (N - 1), s))
    # Perform the multiplication and reshaping of the Xi array
    Xi = numpy.einsum('sij,js->is', self.BigMat, BigCol).reshape((N, n2, s))
    return Xi
```

The second version does precisely the same thing as the first one. Sadly, this second version takes almost 5x the running time of the previous one. My guess is that the cost of assembly of the Big Matrix is too great...

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Using the `time` module could be used to profile: `start = time.time(); propagator.propagateXi(...); print(time.time() - start);`, for comparison between the initial approach, and also to see the relative times for `prepareBigMat` and `propagateXi`.

Comment: I am using cProfile and snakeviz to profile my code, I think it presents more information as compared with simple timing. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Comment: Does profiling confirm your supposition, "My guess is that the cost of assembly of the Big Matrix is too great..."?

Comment: Yes, it does. 

What I meant was that the second approach seemed to be great at first, because there are no 'for' loops in propagateXi(), but it is not. That's why I need more ideas :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the relevance of Big Matrix for these timing calculations? My interpretation is that assembling Big Matrix occurs only once as a fixed cost (i.e., the same `Propagator` is used for calling `propagateXi` multiple times)? But this seems in contrast to your comment that "My guess is that the cost of assembly of the Big Matrix is too great...". When you say that the second version takes 5x the running time, is the assembly of Big Matrix included in that calculation, or is the 5x time difference just comparing `propagateXi`?